# assigning a value to anonymous variable in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to mary two person. I defined X and Y in top of grammar.
My grammar is: `evlendir(X,Y):-` 
I write following code but I can not compare D and B with 1998. 
D is refer to birthdate of `male(X,_,_)` and B is refer to birthdate of `female(X,_,_)` 
and also my database is like male(name,birthdate,deathdate) :

`male(orhan,1978,_).
male(tolga,1982,_).`

`female(secil,1975,_).
female(derya,1982,_).`

PLEASE HELP ME.
[image]

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: Yes. I am writing a family tree in prolog. I did other parts of project but I can not assign a value to anonymous variable. Can you help me in this detail?

Comment: You need to post a complete example that we can copy (i.e., not an image) so we can try to run it. Nobody will try to type in your code from an image *and* try to reconstruct the missing parts.